# Elasticsearch Springboot Integration Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, junit4

I am trying to add an embedded elasticsearch to my spring boot integration test. The problem here is that initializing a node does not work together with spring boot as both should use different test runners.

This is the error I'm getting:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context information for thread: Thread[id=1, name=main, state=RUNNABLE, group=main]. Is this thread running under a class com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner runner context? Add @RunWith(class com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class) to your test class. Make sure your code accesses random contexts within @BeforeClass and @AfterClass boundary (for example, static test class initializers are not permitted to access random contexts).

This is my class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Profile("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
public class ExampleTest extends AbstractElasticSearchIntegrationTest{



    @Autowired
    ExampleController exampleController;


    @Test
    public void deleteExample() throws Exception {
        assert(exampleController.delete("foo",
            "bar",
            null)).equals(new ResponseEntity<DefaultResponse> . 
       (HttpStatus.OK));
    }

}
```

My embedded elasticsearch class is similar to this:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class EmbeddedElasticSearchServer {

private static final String DEFAULT_DATA_DIRECTORY = "target/elasticsearch-data";

private static final String NODE_LOCAL_PROP = "node.local";
private static final String CLUSTER_NAME_PROP = "cluster.name";
private static final String INDEX_GATEWAY_TYPE_PROP = "index.gateway.type";
private static final String PATH_HOME_PROP = "path.home";
private static final String PATH_DATA_PROP = "path.data";
private static final String HTTP_ENABLED_PROP = "http.enabled";

private static final String DEFAULT_DATA_DIR = "target/es-data";
private static final String DEFAULT_CLUSTER = "cluster";

private Node node;
private String dataDirectory;

public EmbeddedElasticSearchServer() {
    this(DEFAULT_DATA_DIRECTORY);
}

public EmbeddedElasticSearchServer(String dataDirectory) {
    this.dataDirectory = dataDirectory;

    Settings elasticsearchSettings = Settings.builder()
            .put(PATH_HOME_PROP, "target")
            .put("http.type", "netty4")
            .put(PATH_DATA_PROP, dataDirectory.toString())
            .put(CLUSTER_NAME_PROP, DEFAULT_CLUSTER)
            .put("http.port", 4040)
            .put("transport.type", "netty4")
            .build();

    try {
        Collection plugins = Arrays.asList(Netty4Plugin.class);
        node = new PluginConfigurableNode(elasticsearchSettings, plugins).start();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Client getClient() {
    return node.client();
}

public RestClient getRestClient() {
    RestClient restClient = getRestClientBuilder().build();
    return restClient;
}

private RestClientBuilder getRestClientBuilder() {
    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder =  RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 4040, "http"))
            .setRequestConfigCallback((b) -> customizedRequestConfig(b))
            .setHttpClientConfigCallback((b) -> customizedHttpClientConfig(b))
            .setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(5000);
    return restClientBuilder;
}
public RestHighLevelClient getRestHighLevelClient() {
    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(getRestClientBuilder());
    return restHighLevelClient;
}
private RequestConfig.Builder customizedRequestConfig(RequestConfig.Builder builder) {
    return builder
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout( 0 ) 
            .setSocketTimeout(5000)
            .setConnectTimeout(5000 );
}


private HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizedHttpClientConfig(HttpAsyncClientBuilder builder) {
    log.info("Setting connection pool, maximum connection {}", 200);
    builder.setMaxConnPerRoute(20)
            .setMaxConnTotal(200);
    return builder;
}

@AfterClass
public void shutdown() {
    try {
        node.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    deleteDataDirectory();
}

@AfterClass
private void deleteDataDirectory() {
    try {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new java.io.File(dataDirectory));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not delete data directory of embedded elasticsearch server", e);
    }
}

private static class PluginConfigurableNode extends Node {
    public PluginConfigurableNode(Settings settings, Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> classpathPlugins) {
        super(InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(settings, null), classpathPlugins);
    }
}
```

Now, the test would run if not for the SpringJUnit4Runner, but that is required to initialize the beans required for the application.

Another constraint that I'll have to adhere to, is that one of the beans that are to be initialized in the application, needs to connect to the embedded elasticsearch to get initialized. So, is there a way to sort out both the problems?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest using [embedded-elasticsearch](https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch) which provides a convenient API to start Elasticsearch in a separate process.